# How could I get changed value from vuetify select by emitting in atomic design pattern?

Tags: vuex, vuetify.js, emit, v-select, atomic-design

I am trying to get the changed value of `vuetify v-select` by using `$emit` but it doesn't work. 
I divided components by applying atomic design pattern (atoms(child component and not to connect with the store), organisms(parent component)) and vuex stores.
I think $emit data is OK but anything doesn't work after the process.

This is for a new application for management page with 
using `vue, vuex, vuetify,` atomic design connecting to API server.

**Components**

**child component - in atoms folder**

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :items="list"
    :label="label"
    v-model="selected"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="name"
    return-object
    @change="changeSelected"
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["list", "label", "defaultSelected"],
  data() {
    return {
      selected: this.defaultSelected
    };
  },
  methods: {
    changeSelected(newValue) {
      console.log(newValue);    // display changed new data
      this.$emit("changeSelected", newValue);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**parent component - in organisms folder**

```
<template>
  <v-select-child
    :select-label="label"
    :select-list="list"
    :default-selected="selected"
    @change-selected="changeSelected"    // problem issue?
  >
  </v-select-child>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    ...
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      list: state => state.list
    })
  },
  methods: {
    changeSelected() {
      console.log("changeSelected");    // doesn't work
      this.$store.dispatch("setSelected", { payload: this.selected });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**vuex stores**

index.js

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    xxx
  },
  state: {
    list: [
      {
        name: "aaaaa",
        id: "001"
      },
      {
        name: "bbbbb",
        id: "002"
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {},
  mutations: {},
  actions: {}
});
```

**xxx.js**

```
export default {
    selected: { id: "001" }
  },

  getters: {
    //
  },

  mutations: {
    updateSelected(state, payload) {
      console.log("payload");    // doesn't work
      console.log(payload);
      state.selected = payload;
      console.log(state.selected);
    }
  },

  actions: {
    setSelected({ commit }, payload) {
      console.log("Action");    // doesn't work
      commit("updateSelected", payload);
    }
  }
};
```

It does not print any console log after `changeSelected` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html#Event-Names)

> Unlike components and props, event names don’t provide any automatic
> case transformation. Instead, the name of an emitted event must
> exactly match the name used to listen to that event.

That means if you emit event like `$emit('changeSelected')`, then you need to use `@changeSelected`. `@change-selected` will not work.

```
 <v-select-child
    :select-label="label"
    :select-list="list"
    :default-selected="selected"
    @changeSelected="changeSelected" 
  >
</v-select-child>
```

Comment: Thank you very much!  However, I have another problem that changed payloads are added inside the others. `payload { payload {payload { id: aaaaa } } }`  Is there any ideas  use `$event` with vuetify v-select without using  vuex store in the child component? I found this article, [http://arm4.hatenablog.com/entry/2018/07/02/162628] but it uses `$store` directly but I would like to use $store in the parent component.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution below:

**child component**

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :label="label"
    :items="list"
    v-model="selected"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="name"
    return-object
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["list", "label", "defaultSelected"],
  computed: {
    selected: {
      get() {
        return this.defaultSelected;
      },
      set(newVal) {
        if (this.selected !== newVal) {
          this.$emit("changeSelected", newVal);
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**parent component**

```
<template>
  <v-select-child
   :label="label"
   :list="list"
   :defaultSelected="selected"
   @changeSelected="changeSelected"  // fix the property using camelCase
  ></v-select-child>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";
export default {
  data() {
    ...
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      list: state => state.list
    })
  },
  methods: {
    changeSelected(val) {   // val: changed object value
      this.$store.dispatch("setSelected", { id:val.id });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use watch;

```
  <v-select
    :label="label"
    :items="list"
    v-model="selected"
    item-value="id"
    item-text="name"
  ></v-select>
</template>

...
watch:{
   selected(){
      this.$emit('changeValue', this.selected.id');
   }
}
...
```

and from parent;

```
<child @changeValue="id = $event" .. />
```